# Mariadb V10.3.6 REGEXP expression for 2 repeat words

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, mariadb

I am looking for REGEXP statement to cactch min 2 or more repeated words in mariadb. Although this code is working in php https://www.regextester.com/?fam=103328
as expected /(\w+\s\w.*)\s.*\1/  I couldn't get it worked in mariadb is there someone help me about this ? how can use this in maria db ?

```
SELECT * FROM hospital where 'title' REGEXP '/(\w+\s\w.*)\s.*\1/'
```

results 0  when there is thousands

Comment: I think you need `REGEXP '\\b(\\w+)\\b.*\\b\\1\\b'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew MySQL returned an empty result for both set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0004 sec )

Comment: Sorry, I was updating the comment, did you try `REGEXP '\\b(\\w+)\\b.*\\b\\1\\b'`?

Comment: What does `v13` in title refer to?

Comment: sorry it meant to be maria db 10.3.6

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this is working but it catch any single repeated words in string. What I want is to catch 2 group of duplicate phrases for example it will catch this "cervical cancer is important cervical cancer rate in the states" (cervical cancer) but not this "cercival cancer is important cervical diane" (cervical) because it's only 1 repeated word not 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, get rid of the enclosing slashes, regex delimiters are not used here. Then, you should double escape the backslashes to define regex escapes inside the pattern.

To match a repeating chunk of word chars, followed with 1+ whitespace chars and then again a chunk of word chars (two space-separated words) you may use

```
REGEXP '\\b(\\w+\\s+\\w+)\\b.*\\b\\1\\b'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cBUkIP/1).

**Details**

- `\\b` - a word boundary
- `(\\w+\\s+\\w+)` - Group 1:

  - `\\w+` - 1+ word chars
  - `\\s+` - 1+ whitespace chars
  - `\\w+` - 1+ word chars
- `\\b` - a word boundary
- `.*` - any 0+ characters, as many as possible
- `\\b\\1\\b` - the same value as is stored in Group 1 as a whole word (in order to avoid matching `put in` in `put in and input insider`).